# Narrow down allowed types in templated using type alias with static_assert

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, static-assert

While still learning template based meta programming, I've come to the following problem:
I've got a templated using type alias, and I want to narrow down the allowed types with `static_assert` but I'm not sure how to write it:

```
using service_func_plain_loop_t = std::function<void(void)>;
using service_func_with_arg_loop_t = std::function<void(std::string)>;
using service_callbacks_t = std::map<event, std::function<bool(void) >>;

template<typename service_loop> using service_functionality_t =
std::pair<service_loop, service_callbacks_t>;
static_assert(
        std::is_convertible<service_loop,service_func_plain_loop_t>.value ||
        std::is_convertible<service_loop,service_func_with_arg_loop_t>.value,
        "service_loop has to be either service_func_plain_loop_t or " 
        "service_func_with_arg_loop_t");
```

This approach fails because of `service_loop` is not declared in the scope of `static_assert`. When checking classes I can just move the assert into the class scope, but what's the syntax here?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean that instantiating `service_functionality_t` with something that isn't convertible to those types should hard-fail?

Comment: @TartanLlama Exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a helper class to do the `static_assert`:

```
template <typename service_loop>
struct service_functionality {
    static_assert(
        std::is_convertible<service_loop,service_func_plain_loop_t>::value ||
        std::is_convertible<service_loop,service_func_with_arg_loop_t>::value,
        "service_loop has to be either service_func_plain_loop_t or " 
        "service_func_with_arg_loop_t");

    using type = std::pair<service_loop, service_callbacks_t>;   
};

template<typename service_loop> using service_functionality_t =
typename service_functionality<service_loop>::type;
```

Note also that it should be `std::is_convertible<T,U>::value` or `std::is_convertible<T,U>{}` rather than `std::is_convertible<T,U>.value`. Although we'll likely get `std::is_convertible_v<T,U>` helper variable templates in C++17.

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36ae934bf86295d8)